# How to do AT+CIPSEND in a sim808 module?

Tags: at-command, sim900

Can anyone help me with a ***sim808*** module , when I send `at+cipsend` command on uart it send just `\r` ( without `\n`). What could be the reason?

[image: stack]

Comment: Please don't use code screenshots. Code should be copy/pasted into the question so that we can run it.  Use the edit link to add the code.

Comment: srry, but that isn`t a part o code, it`s a screenshot from hterm( messages that i get from uart)

Comment: But you should copy that screen output as **pure text** and use that here in the question. Screenshots like that are horrible (and I am a bit surprised that the question has not been downvoted because of it yet).